# Help finding a short story - Protagonist finds out that people have voted for him to die

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, anthology-book

I roughly remember the premise as follows:

A protagonist finds out that a televangelist has encouraged his audience to vote to kill him. In 24 hours he should die.He spends that time trying to stop the process and finally goes to bed resigned not to wake back up. When the time passes everyone who voted for his death dies instead and he's fine.

This was part of a larger anthology I read as a kid. I know I have found it before, but am struggling to do so now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"[Zap Thy Neighbor](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?44210)" by James Hogan, described by the author [here](https://tangentonline.com/interviews-columnsmenu-166/interviews-columnsmenu-166-interviews-columnsmenu-166/classic-james-p-hogan-interview/)

> But also going on is the fact that, through food additives, the
> society has pre-wired everyone’s brain with a particular neural code.
> If three people get your code and then transmit that code, you’re
> zapped. It’s a way to control society’s misfits, to make everyone more
> polite. If you get too far out of hand your private zap code gets
> published. You find everybody getting real polite real quick. Except
> that these two reporters get drunk and piss everybody off. I won’t
> tell you any more about it except to say that a lot of people die.

From my memory, the story ends just like you describe, with the revelation that

> the system that purportedly eliminates the unpopular actually eliminates those willing to kill the unpopular (I think after you've made your n-th vote to kill someone, you die instead).

The anthology you read is likely **How To Save the World** edited ny Charles Sheffield.